# Alamofire download issue

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to download [this picture](https://slove.tulleb.com/uploads/6/6/0/2/66027561/2791411.jpg-1447979839.png) in my code using Alamofire 4.0.0 with Xcode 8.0 and Swift 3.0.

Here is my request:

```
    func download(_ path: String, _ completionHandler: @escaping (Any?) -> ()) {
        let stringURL = "https://slove.tulleb.com/uploads/6/6/0/2/66027561/2791411.jpg-1447979839.png"

        print("Requesting \(stringURL)...")

        _ = Alamofire.download(stringURL)
            .responseData { response in
                print(response)

                if let data = response.result.value {
                    completionHandler(UIImage(data: data))
                } else {
                    completionHandler(nil)
                }
        }
    }
```

I get the following answer from the server:

> FAILURE:
>   responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputFileReadFailed(file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/50400F41-47FD-4276-8903-F48D942D064A/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_D1Aqkh.tmp))

I don't have any idea on how to fix this... Is Alamofire new version having some issues or is it me forgetting something somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Official answer from cnoon (Alamofire member):](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1529)

> Hi @Tulleb,
>
> Apologies for not getting back to you sooner. The example @katopz is
>   not the same type of request. That example demonstrates how to use a
>   data task, not a download task. If you don't wish to download the
>   file, you can instead do the following:
>
> ```
> Alamofire.request(url).responseData { response in
>      guard let data = response.result.value else { return }
>      let image = UIImage(data: data)
>      print(image)
> }
> ```
>
> However, to answer you're original question, you're running into a sandbox permissions issue. We allow you to use the
>   download APIs without specifying a destination closure for operating
>   systems like macOS where you can access files outside of your own
>   sandbox. However, on iOS, you cannot directly access the data of a
>   file that is outside of your sandbox. That's why you are seeing the
>   .inputFileReadFailed error.
>
> There are a couple ways you can solve this issue.
>
> Option 1
>
> You can download the data using the request API as shown above which
>   downloads the image data into memory, not to disk.
>
> Option 2
>
> You can move the file into your sandbox before accessing the data
>   using a destination closure. Here's an example of how to do that:
>
> ```
> let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
> let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,
> .userDomainMask, true)[0]
> let documentsURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath, isDirectory: true)
> let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("image.png")
>
> return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories]) }
>
> Alamofire.download("https://httpbin.org/image/png", to:
> destination).responseData { response in
>     debugPrint(response)
>
>     if let data = response.result.value {
>         let image = UIImage(data: data)
>         print(image)
>     } else {
>         print("Data was invalid")
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> // Outputs:
>
> // [Request]: https://httpbin.org/image/png // [Response]:
>    { URL: https://httpbin.org/image/png
>   } { status code: 200, headers { //     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =
>   "*"; //     "Content-Length" = 8090; //     "Content-Type" =
>   "image/png"; //     Date = "Sat, 24 Sep 2016 21:34:25 GMT"; //
>   Server = nginx; //     "access-control-allow-credentials" = true; // }
>   } // [TemporaryURL]:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/25612024-9A05-4ED5-AF3B-A98E22DEAD7A/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_fD9sXf.tmp
>   // [DestinationURL]:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/25612024-9A05-4ED5-AF3B-A98E22DEAD7A/Documents/image.png
>   // [ResumeData]: 0 bytes // [Result]: SUCCESS: 8090 bytes //
>   [Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 496445664.792, "Initial
>   Response Time": 496445665.651, "Request Completed Time":
>   496445665.655, "Serialization Completed Time": 496445665.655, "Latency": 0.860 secs, "Request Duration": 0.863 secs, "Serialization
>   Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.864 secs } //
>   Optional(, {100, 100}) You MUST use a
>   destination closure if you need to download the file to disk. The
>   temporary file can only be accessed inside the delegate callback which
>   is handled internally in Alamofire. If you do not specify a
>   destination closure on iOS, the temporaryURL will always point to
>   where the temp file was previously stored, but has been cleaned up.
>
> Summary
>
> So in summary, if you don't need to download the data to disk, then
>   you want Option 1. If you do want to save the file on disk, then you
>   want Option 2.
>
> Cheers.

Comment: I was running into the same issue. Thanks for the answer!