# Alamofire - Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed - Xcode 8

Tags: ios, alamofire, xcode8

I get the error in Alamofire.downloand as below:

```
Alamofire.download(URLString).responseData { response in

            if let data = response.result.value {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
            }else{
                print(response.result.error)
            }
        }
```

> Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputFileReadFailed(file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/40167F58-FF4A-4D19-B01A-F8ED90F794DD/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_1dnNQR.tmp)))

Can anyone help solved it or facing same issues?

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `URLString` so we can test that image too?

Comment: Testing url: qqxxzx.com/images/cute-wallpaper/cute-wallpaper-10.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire download issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490390/alamofire-download-issue)

Answer (score 7):

Change the `Alamofire.download` to `Alamofire.request`, it will download. Exact answer for your question, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490390/alamofire-download-issue)